# Sum of a Column resulting from Summarize Function in DAX

Tags: dax

I need to sum the values of column resulting from the table resulting from Summarize Funtion.

For e.g. my Data Set 'Tab' is like this

```
Type        Value    
A             10    
A             10    
A             10    
B             20    
B             20    
B             20    
C             30    
C             30    
C             30
```

The result from `Summarize(Tab,[Type],AVG([Value]))` will be like following

```
A             10
B             20
C             30
```

And the final result required from this result set is 10+20+30 i.e. 60.

Please help

Answer (score 4):

You can use SUMX function.

```
Sum of Avg =
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE ( Tab, [Type], "Total Average", AVERAGE ( Tab[Value] ) ),
    [Total Average]
)
```

It will give you the total if there is not any Type context affecting the measure:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a name for it.

```
Total Value = Summarize(Tab,'Tab'[Type],"Total value",SUM('Tab'[Value])
```

Comment: Thanks looked for something like this for hours on the net, all other answers were complicated and leave out the ' '